# Printing accented characters in Ruby

Tags: ruby, utf-8, character-encoding, aptana

I would like to display this: `Bonne fête`

I have `# encoding: UTF-8` on the very first line of my script. However the result I got is this:

`Bonne f\u00EAte`

Is there something I can do to display the correct character (`ê` instead of `\u00EA`)?

ps:

- I am using: Aptana Studio 3 as IDE, Ruby 1.9.3, and Windows 7
- Windows>Preferences>Workspace>Text file encoding is set to `Other: UTF-8`
- I have tried `# encoding: ISO-8859-1` with no luck.

Comment: Try `Bonne fête.encode('UTF-8')` ...

Comment: `puts "Bonne fête"` works fine on OS X.

Comment: `p "Bonne fête".encode('UTF-8')` gives the same `Bonne f\u00EAte` as stated before...

Comment: How are you displaying this? Does `puts` show it correctly? What does `"Bonne fête".encoding` yield? Can the terminal you're using display UTF-8?

Comment: Show the line of the script, and please be clear whether you are actually running a separate script or if this is some testing in IRB. The escaped Unicode character is what you might expect if you were `.inspect`-ing a String, and seeing the Ruby code representation, as opposed to how the string would be displayed if sent normally to an output device.

Comment: @tadam: you are right `puts`shows it correctly, but `p` does not. `"Bonne fête".encoding`returns `#<Encoding:UTF-8>`.

Comment: @NeilSlater: I am running a script written in Aptana.

Comment: `p "Bonne fête".encode('UTF-8')` prints `"Bonne fête"` in ruby 2.1.5

Comment: @jeake: `p` does an `.inspect`, and as a result, usually displays the Ruby code for your data. You may have noticed it also includes the quotes. Nothing is wrong, it is supposed to happen. Don't use `p` except for debug or utility output. Use `puts` or `print` to output to terminal.